# org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilterException: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry

Tags: spring-security, adfs2.0, spring-saml

I am getting the below exception while I am trying to run my server after configuring my IDP in securityContext.xml.

Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilterException: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry

I saw there is a workaround in http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/saml/108450-getting-error-signature-trust-establishment-failed-for-metadata-entry link where it says, by setting property metadataTrustCheck to false on the ExtendedMetadataDelegate bean which includes your IDP metadata.

But I don't want to update the saml2 core api, instead, is possible to set metadataTrustCheck in the securityContext.xml.  If so, how to set it up.  I tried as given below.  But still getting the same error.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/services/MyMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

My MetadataManager is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/services/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">https://adfsserver1.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">5000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/capital/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">https://adfsserver2.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">5000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Please help on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your complete CachingMetadataManager bean?

Comment: Hey Vladimir, Nice to hear from you. I am using, spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar.  I have not changed any of the exiting core API code.

Comment: Initially I used your saml2-core source and modified the metadataTrustCheck to false in the ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java file and built the jar file.  It worked well.  Now I am trying to use the SNAPSHOT where the above mentioned change wont be there. Instead I can override the metadataTrustCheck value in securityContext.xml by using <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>.  correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I was asking about the CachingMetadataManaer bean configuration, not sources - I want to see how your Spring configuration looks like. The metadtaTrustCheck should work just fine, I suspect you set it on wrong metadata provider. Setting metadataTrustCheck to false is the correct approach.

Comment: In this comment line, i am not able to add the bean. is there any other way to share it.

Comment: You can always edit your question and add more content there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some of your `MetadataProviders` were wrapped in the `ExtendedMetadataDelegate`. You must set the `metadataTrustCheck` flag to `false` on each `MetadataProvider` which should be skipping the trust check, not just on some of them. Define the metadata provider as follows and your problem should be gone:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/services/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                        <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.lang.String">
                                https://adfsserver1.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
                            </value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="int">5000</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/capital/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                        <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.lang.String">
                                https://adfsserver2.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
                            </value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="int">5000</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Marked every ExtendedMetadataDelegate bean with metadataTrustCheck as false, but still get the same error. Config file available [here](https://gist.github.com/mohnish82/ad7501b1b585c9f881b2).

Answer (score 2):

In the Java Config version, I had to manually call the initialize method against the metadataProvider object after I set the trust check flag to false.

```
@SamlBeanAnnotation
@Qualifier("metadata")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException, ResourceException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    for (String file: getSamlProviders()) {
        ResourceBackedMetadataProvider metadataProvider = new ResourceBackedMetadataProvider(new Timer(),
                new org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource("/" + file.trim()));
        metadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());

        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(metadataProvider, new ExtendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        metadataProvider.initialize();
        providers.add(metadataProvider);
    }

    CachingMetadataManager cachingMetadataManager= new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    return cachingMetadataManager;
}
```